# Select the first <h3> element after a class definition

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="location info">
        <h3>Location</h3>
        <h3>should be no stlye</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="skills info">
        <h3>Skills</h3>
        <h3>should be no stlye</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to style the first `h3` element after an info class. I thought this should work, but it dosen't:

```
.info:first-child {
    color: color: rgb(200,50,50);
}
```

Why isn't this working? How should I style the first  element in . info without adding extra markup in the html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a space:

```
.info :first-child
```

The `first-child` pseudo element describes the element itself, not the children of the element. So, without the space you are selecting elements with a class of info that are the first child of their parent.

The space specifies that you are looking for descendants of `.info`.  Since you are looking for just direct children, you should use the child combinator - `>`, and probably also specify only h3 elements:

```
.info > h3:first-child
```

**Edit:** I only noticed the problem with the selector.  As mentioned in other answers ([+1 to user1479606](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15748028/361684)), you have a typo in your style definition as well: `color: color: ...` should be `color: ...`.

Comment: @jamie - your jsfiddle has a error in the style definition. You have `color: color: `. It works when that is corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/vePaX/1/

Answer (score 4):

You're not far away, try this:

```
.info > h3:first-child {
    color: rgb(200,50,50);
}
```

But instead of using something like this, I believe the best approach would be to add a meaningful class to the first h3 - this will make reading the CSS and markup much easier in the future and it will prevent unexpected behavior when editing your markup. For example:

```
.info-title {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also select h3's that are nested deeper than directly after the `.info` element? Like `<div class="info"><div><h3>`? You might want to add a child selector (`>`) between `.info` and `h3:first-child`

Comment: @Steve That'd be a bit more future-proof - I'll add it in, but I prefer adding a class anyway.

Comment: Agree with the class approach, too. :)

Comment: I dislike the class approach. H3 is already a semantically descriptive element. If the first differs semantically from subsequent h3 elements, perhaps they should be h4 instead. If the design calls for a *stylistic* difference for the first header of a section, the `:first-child` selector is perfect. If the design changes in the future to make all the headers uniform, you aren't left with meaningless classes in your html. I frequently will reduce or increase the top margin of the first header in a section. Not because it is semantically different, but because the design needs it.

Comment: To me it seemed like the poster had some modules and the first h3 plays a different role. The specific example that you gave does not warrant a class, but other than that I generally prefer to style module components using class names rather than types - I find it more clear (if a module has an h2 and an h3, what do they even mean?) and more resilient to change (might change the h3 to h2, but it's still a info-title). But markup should be adapted to the context and I hope it'll be useful for someone to have a few pros & cons listed here.

Comment: Ya, it's a subtle difference and certainly subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is not correct, you only need to specify `color` once. You also need to make a more slightly change to your selector:

```
.info > h3:first-child {
    color: rgb(200,50,50);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WSZcS/

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to style the first h3 element after an info class.

```
.info > h3 {
    color: rgb(200,50,50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your h3 tag is not the first child element you can use

```
.info > h3:first-of-type {
    color: rgb(200,50,50);
}
```